# Javascript dictionary and to add values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a definition of my dictionary like this

```
const dData: {
    [mydate: string]:  {[stuff in Bag]?: IbagData};
  }={}

export enum Bag{
  toys= "TOYS",
  books= "BOOKS",
}

export interface IbagData{
  data: ImyDataArray[];
}
```

It's empty and I need to be able to add entries to it.

I have `const [dateSelection, setDateSelection] = useState("8/26/2020");`

When I try to assign value to mydate like this it does not like it.

```
dData[mydate] = dateSelection;   // This one says Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ toys?: IbagData| undefined; books?: IbagData| undefined; }'
```

It does not even recognize my date.

After that, I want to be able to assign

```
dData[mydate][Bag.toys] = Data
```

but before that, I need to see if there is an entry in my dictionary for that day already and I try to do

```
dData[mydate][Bag.toys]
```

It does not like that also.
I guess what I am trying to see how to populate a dictionary dData with that structure.

Comment: You need to include definitions for 'Bag' and 'IbagData' because as it stands Bag is both a type AND a concrete object which is obviously impossible.

Comment: Sure I just added them,

Comment: "*It does not like that also*" - what's the error message?

Comment: All that was (Bag and IbagData) were already in my project, I just added that to the post. Error messages are shown above.

Comment: Oh this line dData[mydate][Bag.toys] Cannot read property 'toys' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
const dData: Record<string, Record<Bag, IbagData>> = {}
```

**edit:**

`dData[mydate] = dateSelection` This doesn't work because 'dateSelection' is a string, and you want to be putting in an object that looks like this:

```
dData[mydate] = {
   [Bags.toys]: "some IBagData object"
}
```

**edit2:**

The question was hard to understand but I've finally figured out what you're asking and your original type definition was fine. Here's a working example:

```
type IbagData = "bag data"

export enum Bag {
    toys = "TOYS",
    books = "BOOKS",
}

const dData: { [THIS_NAME_DOES_NOT_MATTER_AT_ALL: string]: { [stuff in Bag]?: IbagData} } = {}
const dateSelection = "8/27/2020"

console.log(dData[dateSelection]) // This undefined so we cannot index it.
// Let's initialize it
dData[dateSelection] = {};
// OK, now we can index it.
dData[dateSelection][Bag.toys] = "bag data"

console.log(dData) // { '8/27/2020': { TOYS: 'bag data' } }
```

Comment: humm.. Interesting but mydate needs a value too.. It needs to be something like this.. 8/26/2020 :{toys : myToysData, books:myBooksData}   I need to be able to assign value to mydate which is stored in dateselection and a string.

Comment: @Sarah then simply `dData[dateSelection] = { [Bags.toys]: "some IBagData object" }`

Comment: @Sarah I think I misunderstood your entire question for a bit, but I've given a working example that I hope helps.

Comment: It seems like both dData[dateSelection] = { [Bags.toys]: "some IBagData object" } and dData[dateSelection][Bag.toys] = "bag data" are working.. Seems like.. Do you mind explaining how this is built. I am so confused on why [] are used and not . notations and how did it assign dateselection to mydate.

Comment: Also if I do if (dData[dateSelection][Bag.toys]) it gives a runtime error saying "Cant read property of toys undefined"..

Comment: Still confirming your suggestions please stay with me.

Comment: @Sarah I edited the answer to include 'THIS_NAME_DOES_NOT_MATTER_AT_ALL' to hopefully help you understand more that mydate does not actually exist, it is just a label on the index signature that I wish typescript would just remove. We use the brackets instead of dot notation because we are accessing indices using a variable and not a raw identifier. You could, for example. just do this: `dData[dateSelection].TOYS = "bag data"` and it would be the same.

Comment: So I take it back Cannot set property 'toys' of undefined is coming when I try to set the value like you suggested dData[dateSelection][Bag.toys] = "bag data"  It was compiling but run time error coming.

Comment: Trying your other suggestion of dData[dateSelection] = { [Bags.toys]: "some IBagData object" }

Comment: When you say  "using a variable and not a raw identifier" I am assuming you are saying toys is a raw identifier that is why we can use it with dot and dateselection is variable and that we need to access using brackets.. correct?

Comment: So it seems like dData[dateSelection] = { [Bags.toys]: "some IBagData object" } to assign values.. I dont understand the structure there.. Do you mind explaining why this worked but other one did not please?

Comment: Also, I do need to check if  dData[dateSelection][Bag.toys] already exists or not because I dont want it added again.. and it gives a run time error.

Comment: @Sarah yes, you have to check if it already exists if you don't want it added again.